# Export data returned by 'fetch' from a separate .js file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

This is my code

```js
const data = () => fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mp441")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(obj => data = obj);

const RECORD_NOS=Object.keys(data).length-1;

export {data, RECORD_NOS}
```

I am trying to get the json data hosted at the above url, save the data in a variable and export it for use in various places in my React application but unfortunately it gives the following error.

```js
./src/resources/index.js
Syntax error: D:/Users/kumahay/Documents/lending-referrals-app/src/resources/index.js: "data" is read-only

  1 | const data = () => fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mp441")
  2 |       .then(response => response.json())
> 3 |       .then(obj => data = obj);
    |                    ^
  4 | 
  5 | const RECORD_NOS=Object.keys(data).length-1;
  6 |
```

I have tried console logging instead of assigning the data but it doesn't work. Apparently the data is not being fetched. How to better frame this code so that it works as expected? I am a beginner in javaScript so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to set the *const* data inside your code. You cannot set the value of const.

Answer (score 11):

I think you should read more about async functions, Promises and fetch. The best way is export `getData` function, remove `.then(obj => data = obj)` and use it in any other module like this

*getData.js*

```
export const getData = () => fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mp441")
  .then(response => response.json())
```

*anyOtherFile.js*

```
import {getData} from './path/to/getData.js';

export const someFunc = () => {
   getData().then(data => {
       /* do what you want to do in promise resolve callback function */
   })
}
```

or with async/await notation

*getData.js*

```
export const getData = async () => fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mp441")
  .then(response => response.json())
```

*anyOtherFile.js*

```
import {getData} from './path/to/getData.js';

export const someFunc = async () => {
    const data = await getData();
}
```

Comment: `async () => fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/mp441")...` this doesn't make sense. If you don't use `await` you don't need to make your function `async`

Comment: As you can see in `anyOtherFile.js` await is used =) But you are totally right)

Comment: But in anyOtherFile.js file how do i export the data as a json object?

Comment: @AkshayKumar You **can't** export pure result of  an async request

Answer (score -2):

> Please change the name of data to response data and instead of
>   constant use variable. Constant cannot be overwritten but variable
>   can.

Example:

var data = "something";

```
const name ="Japarsathik";

var salary = "$5000";
```

Comment: Even if he changes name his `const RECORD_NOS=Object.keys(data).length-1;` constant will cause `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`, because result is undefined