# Export JSON object to another .js without class declaration react-native

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch

I am developing a mobile app which makes GET calls using fetch api. I am stuck in that I am trying to export json object( fetched from server with fetch method) to another .js file to be used as array, But when I import my function in another.js (below), it returns nothing. I tested my fetch method with console so it works as expected, however I am unable to process data in another.js file. By the way, I have searched a lot and found this post [Helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380991/export-data-returned-by-fetch-from-a-separate-js-file-in-react), but not worked.

**Below code is implementation of fetch part and exporting it.(Products.js)**

```
import React, { PureComponent,Component } from "react";
 import { connect } from "react-redux";
 import { View } from "react-native";
 import { productsDataSelector } from      "../../Products/ProductsSelectors";
 import ProductsList from "../../ProductsList/ProductsList";
 import Product from "../../Product/Product";
 import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from "react-navigation";
 import AnotherComponent from "../../Products/ProductsReducer";
 class Products extends PureComponent  {

  render() {
const { navigation } = this.props;

const { productsData } = this.props;
return (


  <View>
    <ProductsList list={productsData} isSortable>
      {product => <Product product={product} />}
    </ProductsList>
  </View>
     );
  }
}

 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   productsData: productsDataSelector(state)
 });
  export  const  getMoviesFromApiAsync = () =>
 fetch('http://localhost:8080/JweSecurityExample/rest/security/retrieveItems')
.then((response) => response.json())


export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  null
     ) (Products);
```

**Below code is another.js where importing fetch function and processing returning json object without class declaration implemented.**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
 import {getMoviesFromApiAsyncc} from "../screens/Products/Products";


 const fakeData = [];



 export const someFunc = () => {

 fetch('http://localhost:8080/JweSecurityExample/rest/security/retrieveItems')
   .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) =>     console.log("responsee:"+JSON.stringify(responseJson)))
  .then((responseJson) =>  {fakeData:JSON.stringify(responseJson)})

  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
      });

};
someFunc();

const initialState = {
  data:this.fakeData

};

export default (state = initialState,action) => {
  return state;
};
```

Any recommendations ?? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where in your code do you call `someFunc` and one more thing you need to wrap the object that you return from `someFunc` in braces otherwise it will be treated as the function's body.

```
export const someFunc = () => {
  getMoviesFromApiAsync().then(response => {
    fakeData = JSON.stringify(response)
  })
};
someFunc();
```

I suggest that you move `getMoviesFromApiAsync` to a separate file and call it from your component to get the list of movies.

**api.js**

```
export const getMoviesFromApiAsync = () =>
  fetch('http://localhost:8080/JweSecurityExample/rest/security/retrieveItems')
    .then((response) => response.json());
```

**product.js**

```
import React, { PureComponent,Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { productsDataSelector } from      "../../Products/ProductsSelectors";
import ProductsList from "../../ProductsList/ProductsList";
import Product from "../../Product/Product";
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from "react-navigation";
import AnotherComponent from "../../Products/ProductsReducer";
// import getMoviesFromApiAsync
import { getMoviesFromApiAsync } from 'PATH_TO_API.JS'


class Products extends Component {

  async componentDidMount(){
    const list = await getMoviesFromApiAsync();
    console.log(list);
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    const { productsData } = this.props;
    return (


      <View>
        <ProductsList list={productsData} isSortable>
          {product => <Product product={product} />}
        </ProductsList>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I dont know how to set fakeData with returning fetch response so you are right someFunc is meaningless. Then, how can I call getMoviesFromApiAsync function to set fakeData variable without class declaration ?

Comment: nothing wrong with your export/import of `getMoviesFromApiAsync`. please check updated answer on how to set fakeData. And remember that you need to call `someFunc`.

Comment: I tried that `export const someFunc = () => {
   getMoviesFromApiAsyncc().then(response => {fakeData:JSON.stringify(response)
   }).then(response => console.log("log:"+JSON.stringify(response)))
};
someFunc();` Nothing changed I think It does not call someFunc() because there is no log. Do I need to create class for calling someFunc() ?

Comment: Are you Importing `another.js` in any other file?. Actually the whole flow is kind of not correct. You shouldn't have `getMoviesFromApiAsync` in the same file as the your component. you can have a new file `api.js` that has `getMoviesFromApiAsync` and then you can call it inside your `componentDidMount` function. please check updated answer.

Comment: No I dont import another.js. In products.js I am able to get fetch response by using componentDidMount but I need to pass this returned json object to another.js file so I can change the content of fakeData. Simply I need to assign fetch result to fakeData variable in another.js file somehow . For this reason I am exporting getMoviesFromApiAsync to handle in another.js.

Comment: If you don't import `another.js` anywhere then the code won't run even if it is inside a class.

Comment: Thanks Abdelrahman, fetch works in another.js file :) I edited another.js file one more thing I need to do is "assigning returned fetch response to fakeData " because right now fakeData returns me [object object] not json response. Is it true assignment(fakeData) above in another.js  ?

Comment: that's because `response.json()` returns a promise. you can fix it like this `fetch('http://localhost:8080/JweSecurityExample/rest/security/retrieveItems')
    .then((response) => response.json()).then(res => res);`

Comment: Then this should work but still fakeData is empty array.`export const someFunc = () => {

  fetch('http://localhost:8080/JweSecurityExample/rest/security/retrieveItems')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(res1=> res1)
      .then((res1) => console.log("responsee:"+JSON.stringify(res1)))
      .then((res1) =>  {fakeData:JSON.stringify(res1)})

      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });

};
someFunc();`

Comment: `fetch('http://localhost:8080/JweSecurityExample/rest/security/retrieveItems') .then((response) => response.json()).then(res => { fakeData = res });

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, fetch returns json as below `[{"id":"1","title":"Lugo","price":10,"category":"Coffee","images":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dznqctqoe/image/upload/v1550652877/ristretto-bianco.jpg","description":"Double shot with cream"},{"id":"2","title":"Ristretto","price":10,"category":"Coffee","images":"https://res.cloudinary.com/dznqctqoe/image/upload/v1550652877/ristretto-bianco.jpg","description":"Double shot with milk"}]`. But when I assign returned data to fakeData as you suggest, fakeData returns something like fakedata:[ ] in logs.

Comment: I think better move to chat because this is not related to original question. and please mark the answer as correct if it answers your original question.