# Why Javascript cannot read

Tags: javascript

```
const data = [];

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=b78ab1b5579e14c01def23c7f72c18df',
    success: result => {
        data.push(result)
    }
})

export default data;
```

and i try to print data with console.log()

```
import data from "./data.js";
console.log(data);
console.log(data[0])
```

result undefined why ???

```
[]0: {page: 1, total_results: 10000, total_pages: 500, results: Array(20)}length: 1__proto__: Array(0) index.js:193
undefined
```

why undefined ??

Comment: cant you just copy / paste the code instead of making images?

Comment: It takes less time to paste the code then cropping images. I bet on that. Please add your code.

Comment: You should post the code here..not the image to ans. your question

Comment: sorry i fixed it

Comment: What went wrong ? Tip: answer your own question and get some points :)

Answer (score 0):

The `undefined` value is generated by data[0].
If you want to access the of movies, that array is stored in `results`.
So you can access it by using `data.results[0]`.

```
import data from "./data.js";
console.log(data);
console.log(data.results[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your JSON is in string form (meaning it is a string of text, and not a javascript object)

instead of `console.log(data[0])`, try `console.log(JSON.parse(data)[0])`.

This will parse the string as a JSON object so it can properly index it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380991/export-data-returned-by-fetch-from-a-separate-js-file-in-react

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code little bit, you should use **async = false** in your "$.ajax()" request.

```
let data=[];
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular? 
           api_key=b78ab1b5579e14c01def23c7f72c18df',
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        data=result
    }
})

export default data;
```

And print data with console.log

```
import data from "./data.js";
console.log(data.page);
console.log(data.results)
let items = data.results
for(let i=0;i<items.length;i++){
  console.log(items[i]. id)
  console.log(items[i]. popularity);
  console.log(items[i]. title);
  console.log(items[i]. overview);
  console.log(items[i]. release_date);
  console.log(items[i]. vote_count);
}
```